# How to use npm command on vscode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am new to Vscode when m trying to install it it shows:
PS C:\Users\manim> node -v
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- node -v
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

PS C:\Users\manim> npm -v
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npm -v
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: can someone help me with this????

Comment: Does Node work outside VS Code?

Comment: visit this site. https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the errors, I'd say you just don't have node installed. Try running those commands in a command prompt (you can get one up by pressing the windows key and R together, then typing cmd and pressing enter). If it says the same thing, make sure you've got Node installed.